# Creating a UWP solution in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, uwp, .net-core

I'm trying to create an UWP application in Visual Studio Code.

I want to create an app with a ribbon like interface (the interface used in Microsoft office), and since I this is my very first attempt to use VSCode I have no idea how to create the project. At the VSCode terminal help I saw a many different templates available to create projects, but I'm not sure which I should choose.

Comment: Have you tried windows forms?

Comment: I don't recall VSCode provide any templates unless it's something recently new that i'm not aware of. Did you mean `dotnet new` templates? AFAIK I don't think `dotnet new` have UWP project template. https://github.com/dotnet/templating/wiki/Available-templates-for-dotnet-new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using VSCode and the `dotnet` CLI, it doesn't have any built in methods of creating a UWP project.

An alternative if you're purely focused on using a "Ribbon" design is the WinForms Ribbon project, which is FOSS, actively maintained and can be found [here,](https://github.com/RibbonWinForms/RibbonWinForms) with older detailed documentation on how to use it [here.](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/364272/Easily-Add-a-Ribbon-into-a-WinForms-Application)

Comment: I need to use UWP because I must use the ArcGIS Runtime SDK for .NET (UWP and Xamarin.Forms). I need to know if our team will be able to develop the solution using the VSCode or if we must acquire the Visual Studio 2019 in order to develop with the API.

Comment: In that case, you will 100% need Visual Studio, no way around it to my knowledge.